# NSDate column with time, need to fetch back unique value based on day only

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsdate, nsfetchrequest

I want to get back unique dates with only days/months/year from source as: "2017-02-25 22:53:43"
"2017-02-25 23:01:42"
"2017-04-26 17:08:26"
"2017-04-26 17:15:41"

column name is "date", the result should be [2017-02-25, 2017-02-26] if based days; [2017-02, 2017-04] if based on month; and [2017] based on years. I think need to use NSFetchRequest.predicate, but not sure how to do that.

Comment: This link explains in objectiveC, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23704906/how-to-count-unique-dates-of-coredata-objects

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a `fetchedResultsController` and `sectionNameKeyPath`

1. Add read-only properties to the managedObject subclass for `day_month_year`, `month_year` and `year`.
2. in your fetchRequest sort by `date`
3. for  `sectionNameKeyPath` use one of the properties you created.
4. the information you want is in the fetchedResultsController property `sections`

The method that you created for `sectionNameKeyPath` is called for every object.  So don't do something expensive like create a `NSCalendar`.